# REACT 16.3 - render props array as map (optionally)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to render out a mapped array supplied by props. The trouble is that the array is not always available depending on the parent's state. If I try to apply a map to a non-existent array, I get an error (naturally!). So I've tried to set a default empty array to get past the error.

If I set the default REACT thinks I'm trying to map over an object. The following code has been simplified for example purposes, but the end result is the same:

```
export class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // This array is not always available
            // It's actually a deep property in an object
            // done here for simplicity
            myArray: [{name: 'foo'},{name: 'bar'}],
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child myArray={this.state.myArray} />
        );
    }

} 


import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Child extends Component {

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.myArray); //=> [{...},{...}] Array
        console.log(typeof this.props.myArray); //=> Object (wuh???)

        this.props.myArray.map((item) => console.log(item.name)); //=> 'foo' then 'bar'

        // Supply a default empty array here to avoid mapping an undefined
        const list = this.props.myArray || [];

        list.map((item) => {
            return (
                <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <ul> {list} </ul>
        );
    }

}
```

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

If I hard code the array and leave out the default empty array, I don't get an error:

```
const list = this.props.myArray.map((item) => {
            return (
                <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
            );
        });
```

Any ideas on how I can apply a map to a conditional array?

Comment: Just as a side note: There is no type "array" in javascript. An array is also just an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use default props for your Child component as an empty array:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        const list = this.props.myArray.map((item) =>(
            <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
        ));

        return (
            <ul> {list} </ul>
        );
    }
}

Child.defaultProps = {
    myArray: []
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`.map` returns a new array rather than modifying the existing array (which you shouldn't anyway, since props are meant to be read-only).

You can assign `.map` to a new variable, or do the mapping directly in JSX:

```
<ul>{list.map(item => <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>)}</ul>
```

You can also just do `{(this.props.myArray || []).map(...)}` or use default props, or use `[]` (instead of `null` etc) for your initial state in parent component corresponding to `props.myArray`.